# Can't figure out how to get rid of this duplicate key error in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've been stuck on this error for a few hours, and I cannot figure out what is causing the duplicate key error.

The key that is duplicated is null, and I don't know what this refers to. Here is the error:

```
{ MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: my_db.schools.$username_1  dup key: { : null }
```

I have a School schema:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var schoolSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    location: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },
    code: Number,
    members: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        }
    ],
    cluborgs: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Cluborg"
        }
    ],
    date_joined: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

schoolSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("School", schoolSchema);
```

And some routes related to this Schema:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var School = require('../models/school');
var middleware = require('../middleware');

//index
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    School.find({}, function(err, allSchools) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("schools/index", {schools: allSchools});
        }
    });
});

//new
router.get("/new", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render("schools/new");
});

//create
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    var author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    };
    
    var school = {
        name: req.body.school.name,
        location: req.body.school.location,
        author: author,
        code: req.body.school.code
    };
    School.create(school, function(err, newlyCreated) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            req.flash("success", "Successfully created " + newlyCreated.name);
            res.redirect("/schools");
        }
    });    
});

//show
router.get("/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    School.findById(req.params.id)
        .populate("cluborgs")
        .exec(function(err, foundSchool) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.render("schools/show", {school: foundSchool});
            }
    });  
});

//edit
router.get("/:id/edit", middleware.checkSchoolOwnership, function(req, res) {
    School.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundSchool) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("schools/edit", {schools: foundSchool});
        }
    });
});

//update
router.put("/:id", middleware.checkSchoolOwnership, function(req, res) {
    School.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.school, function(err, updatedSchool) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            req.flash("success", "Successfully updated school.");
            res.redirect("/schools/" + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});

//destroy
router.delete("/:id", middleware.checkSchoolOwnership, function(req, res) {
    School.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.redirect("/schools");
        } else {
            res.redirect("/schools");
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router; //put this in EVERY single one of your routes file to get rid of router errors
```

The error arises when I create a second school.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Removing  `unique: true` from a Mongoose property doesn't remove the index from MongoDB automatically.

Furthermore, if you remove a property completely from a Mongoose schema it doesn't delete related indexes from MongoDB automatically either.

So it looks like in your case, MongoDB is still expecting a unique School.username value that you've removed from the schema, and is thus defaulting as null value for every document - triggering the unique constraint.

I personally use the MongoDB CLI to remove such indexes if it ever occurs, although I suspect setting `unique: false` on the property would work too.

Comment: Should I add unique: false to school.author.username?

Comment: If that was what initially had `unique: true`, yes. It should be fine to remove it after Mongoose updates the MongoDB model.

Comment: That didn't fix it. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: It appears that the duplicate key error occurs anytime I try to add a second school, even if I switch users.